# I am having issues with Array and the element thereof

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create an array that stores String and sequentially display it after some time just like the image slideshow, I got everything right except what I don't get is I don't know please any help rendered will be greatly appreciated. This is the code:

```
var addressChange = ["Our Location", "Where to get us", "We reside here"];
var addressBar = document.getElementById("addressBar");
var addressIndex = 0;

function changeAddress() {
    addressBar.setAttribute("p", addressChange[addressIndex]);
    addressIndex++;
    if (addressIndex >= addressChange.length) {
        addressIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is attribute `p` supposed to be doing?

Comment: _"I got everything right except what I don't get is I don't know please any help rendered will be greatly appreciated"_ makes no sense. Please add a detailed explanation.

Comment: The title of the question is supposed to describe the problem you've faced, not your experience when trying to solve it. Also, if you don't know what you're missing, how would we know that? Please edit your question, and explain what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood what you want, anyways here is my shoot:
https://jsfiddle.net/1ctquynr/5/

```
<div id = "addressBar"></div>
<script>
var number = 0;
var addressChange = ["Our Location", "Where to get us", "We reside here"];
var addressBar = document.getElementById("addressBar");

setInterval(changeArray, 5000); //change it every few seconds

function changeArray(){
    addressBar.innerHTML = addressChange[number]; //change the innerHTML according to the current array property
    number++;
    if (number === addressChange.length) //reset
    number = 0;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @RunningFromShia it solved the problem. to others I am sorry if I caused some headache.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML, I think you want to change the `innerText` of whatever element contains the strings.

Replacing the first line of your `changeAddress` function with this, maybe:

```
addressBar.innerText = addressChange[addressIndex];
```

Can you share your HTML to help give more context?